# QueryDSL literals, numbers, boolean in select list

Tags: querydsl

I have a problem with

```
return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(query
    .from(rp)
    .list(ConstructorExpression.create(IzvjesceRacunskiPlanResultset.class,
        rp.rpID,
        rp.gdp,
        rp.number, 
        BOOLEAN VALUE
            )
```

class is as follows:

Integer;
String;
Integer;
Boolean;

I am trying to get fix value in select list that is of Boolean type, but all my efforts were in vain.

i was trying to write:

```
Boolean.True
BooleanTemplate.True
rp.gdp.length() > 0
```

and none of those were correct.

All the time i got no pointer exception

How to achive fix Boolean or bool value in select list (something like Expressions.constant("Text"))??

Comment: Could you provide the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry m8, i got frustrated so i changed the class constructor, passed literal, and in constructor did comparison :-)

Comment: Ok, let me know when you come across this again.